# Feature count of my QGIS geopackage vector layer different by 1 less feature, than when the layer is exported as a DXF

Tags: qgis, geopackage, dxf

So when I put the geopackage into QGIS the feature count says there are 7519 features.

I then export this layer as a DXF and when I open it in Rhino it states there are 7520 hatches.

See images below.

As I have 7519 values for the building heights this completely disrupting the data tree, so that the height values are not allocated to the correct buildings.

Does anybody know what would be causeing this difference?

Would anybody know a solution or if there is a work around?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your building heights  are Annotation (Labels) in the dxf file but without the source file this is an assumption.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. When you find which feature gets split into two in the conversion you can maybe also see something special in the geometry, or ask help from here or from the gdal-dev mailing list.